# How to pass data from a plugin to partial in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins, partial

I have a problem with Zend Framework. I created a plugin that requests some data from a database.

```
<?php
class Blog_Plugin_Navigation extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
    public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        $navigation = new Application_Model_NavigationMapper();

        $view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
        $view->navigation = $navigation->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

In my layout.phtml I use this:

```
<ul>
    <?=$this->partialLoop('navigation-item.phtml', $this->navigation)?>
</ul>
```

When I use print_r to print out the array I get the values from my database, but if I visit my website I just get no values. navigation-item.phtml looks like this:

```
<li><a href="<?=$this->url?>"><?=$this->text?></a></li>
```

I just get this:

```
<li><a href=""></a></li>
```

Where is my mistake? Would be really nice, if someone could help me. :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get for `var_dump($navigation->fetchAll())` and then what do you get for `var_dump($this->url, $this->text)` in the partial template?

Comment: For `var_dump($navigation->fetchAll())` I get an array with my values I want to show and for `var_dump($this->url, $this->text)` I get NULL values. :/

Comment: Ok, I wonder if you also get `NULL` for `$this->navigation` in your `layout.phtml` script?  I would think the variable is assigned there, so maybe its getting lost somehow with the partialLoop.  Are your values inside the `$navigation` array objects or array?  What do you get if you try `<?=$this['url']?>` and `<?=$this['text']?>`?

Answer (score 2):

Repalce

```
<?=$this->partialLoop('navigation-item.phtml', $this->navigation)?>
```

with

```
<?=$this->partialLoop('navigation-item.phtml', $this->navigation)->setObjectKey('model')?>
```

Then replace

```
<li><a href="<?=$this->url?>"><?=$this->text?></a></li>
```

with

```
<li><a href="<?=$this->model->url?>"><?=$this->model->text?></a></li>
```

Comment: +1. I always end up passing an array: `$this->partial('my_partial.phtml, array('model' => $mydata));` Using `setObjectKey()` feels better to me. Thanks!